# How to add woocommerce product in cart based on subtotal and categories

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating a woocommerce function that allows me to add a specific product to the cart based on the following conditions:

1. specific categories
2. total cost of the products higher than a value that I have defined
   in $ min_price

I was able to get that based on the category, woocommerce adds the indicated product.
Unfortunately I can't describe the flow that does this when the total value of the products is higher than the $ min_price.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'auto_add_item_based_on_product_category', 10, 1 );
    function auto_add_item_based_on_product_category( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;
        
    $min_price     = 77.47; // The minimal cart amount

    $required_categories = array('computer-based', 'esami-paper-based'); // Required product category(ies)
    $added_product_id = 5065; // Specific product to be added automatically
    $matched_category = false;
    $matched_subtotal = false;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
        // Check for product category
        if( has_term( $required_categories, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $matched_category = true;
        }
        // Check if specific product is already auto added
        if( $item['data']->get_id() == $added_product_id ) {
            $saved_item_key = $item_key; // keep cart item key
        }
        // Check it the minimum subtotal is reached
        if ( !empty( $product_subtotal > $min_price ) ) {
            $matched_subtotal = true;
        }
    }

    // If specific product is already auto added but without items from product category and minimun subtotal is not reached
    if ( isset($saved_item_key) && ! $matched_category && ! $matched_subtotal ) {
        $cart->remove_cart_item( $saved_item_key ); // Remove specific product
    }
    // If there is an item from defined product category and subtotal reached and specific product is not in cart
    elseif ( ! isset($saved_item_key) && $matched_category && $matched_subtotal ) {
        $cart->add_to_cart( $added_product_id ); // Add specific product
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check below code works for me. I am just a beginner in this

```
     add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'check_cart_outlet_items' );
  function check_cart_outlet_items() {
  $categories = array('computer-based', 'esami-paper-based'); // Defined targeted product categories
  $threshold  = 500; // Defined threshold amount
  $added_product_id = 24589; // Incentive product we are giving away
  $product_id = 24589;
  ///$added_product_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $free_product ); // 
  (equivalent to $prod_unique_id)
  $cart       = WC()->cart;
  $cart_items = $cart->get_cart();
  $subtotal   = $cart->subtotal;
  $subtotal  += $item['line_total'] + $item['line_tax'];
  $found      = false;

foreach( $cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    // Check for specific product categories
    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $found = true; // A category is found   
        
          break; // Stop the loop
    }
     
}

if ( $found && $subtotal < $threshold ) {
 
    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
  $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
  if ( $cart_item_key ) WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
    
    
}
 elseif ($found && $subtotal > $threshold )
 {
     
    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
    $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
     if ( !($cart_item_key) ){
      $cart->add_to_cart( $added_product_id ); // Add specific product
    }
   }
 }
```